# EF6 LazyLoadingEnabled enabled but loads related objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I use EF 6 with my database.
I call constructor ctx=new EntityContext(). Then try to get ctx.Set() for example. LazyLoadingEnabled = true by default. But method returns collection with included related objects. More over, it looks like objects are recursively looped. What am I done wrong? Why lazy loading isn't work?
I also start SQL profiler, I'm not much familiar with it, but...
I start monitoring in profiler, then start test application and... the only request I saw is request to my table and no other requests to related tables.
Request looks like:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[CreateDate] AS [CreateDate], 
[Extent1].[Type] AS [Type], 
[Extent1].[Status] AS [Status]
FROM [dbo].[Task] AS [Extent1]
```

thats all, but debugger show entity with related objects. Why so?

Comment: Do you copy your retrieved entities to other objects (DTOs) using libraries like AutoMapper?

Comment: Are you running SQL Profiler while looking at the objects in the debugger?

Comment: ...and what do you mean by "objects are recursively looped"?

Comment: Also be aware that Visual Studio debugger will trigger lazy loading when you add the entity to Watch, and expand its properties.

Comment: I think you are confused / mixing with the Lazy Loading definition. Lazy Loading means when there is any access to the property it will be loaded, but if there isn't, it will not be loaded, just like load on demand, for example this code `var activities = task.Activities;` will load the activities if it hasn't been loaded, unless Eager Loading already happens at the beginning

Comment: Did you try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue here is not EF loading the related object, but YOU loading them!

If you're looking at a collection in the debugger in VS, then you expand a collection, EF will go and query the database for the related collection (the same as if you did it in code).

If you watch SQL profiler when you do this, you should see it go and perform a second query at that point.

EF works via dynamic proxies, and expanding a collection in the debugger is the equivalent of working with the object in code, and calling `MyObject.TheCollectionProperty.ToList()`

Lazy loading just means that the SQL needed to populate the related collection isn't going to be executed unless you try to access the related collection (as opposed to a single up front query with a join).
Sometimes this is desirable, sometimes this isn't. It will depend on how your application logic wants to work.

Comment: Look's like it's all because of VS debugger. I add Include() method and profiler shows another query with JOIN. But why sql profiler do not show queries from VS debugger... that is a question )

Comment: It will do, if you have the right settings, how are you establishing that it's not?